# Jquery autocomplete height of each item suggested

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an autocomplete input working fine but the suggested list items Height are too small so my problem is that the web app is to use from a tablet and it is difficult to select one item because are too small for fingers
here is my attempt:

```
.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget {
font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
heigth: 30px;
}
```

font size is working, but Heigth it is not working. What I am missing? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that `.ui-autocomplete.ui-widget` is a selector for a `p` tag or something similar. In this case, CSS `height` would not work. You have to use either `line-height` or `padding`.

For example:

`line-height: 3.5;`

or

`padding: 10px 0px;`